# docker-compose up gets stuck at .env doesn't exist

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, environment-variables, environ

I want to insert environmental variables from an .env file into my containerized Django application, so I can use it to securely set Django's settings.py.

*However on $docker-compose up I receive part of an UserWarning which apparently originates in the django-environ package (and breaks my code):*

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/environ/environ.py:628: UserWarning: /app/djangoDocker/.env doesn't exist - if you're not configuring your environment separately, create one. web      |   warnings.warn(

The warning breaks at that point and (although all the container claim to be running) I can neither stop them from that console (zsh, Ctrl+C) nor can I access the website locally. What am I missing? Really appreciate any useful input.

**Dockerfile:** (located in root)

```
# pull official base image
FROM python:3.9.5

# set environment variables, grab via os.environ
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1

# set work directory
WORKDIR /app

# install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# add entrypoint script
COPY ./entrypoint.sh ./app

# run entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]

# copy project
COPY . /app
```

**docker-compose.yml** (located in root; I've tried either using env_file or environment as in the comments)

```
version: '3'

services:

    web:
      build: .
      container_name: web
      command: gunicorn djangoDocker.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
      volumes:
        - .:/app
      ports:
        - "8000:80"
      env_file:
        - .env
      # environment:
      #   BASE_URL: ${BASE_URL}
      #   SECRET_KEY: ${SECRET_KEY}
      #   ALLOWED_HOSTS: ${ALLOWED_HOSTS}
      #   DEBUG: ${DEBUG}
      #   SQL_ENGINE: ${SQL_ENGINE}
      #   SQL_DATABASE: ${SQL_DATABASE}
      #   SQL_USER: ${SQL_USER}
      #   SQL_PASSWORD: ${SQL_PASSWORD}
      #   SQL_HOST: ${SQL_HOST}
      #   SQL_PORT: ${SQL_PORT}
      #   EMAIL_HOST_USER: ${EMAIL_HOST_USER}
      #   EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD: ${EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD}
      #   TEMPLATE_DIR: ${TEMPLATE_DIR}
      depends_on:
        - pgdb

    pgdb:
      image: postgres
      container_name: pgdb
      environment:
        - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
        - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/

    nginx:
      build: ./nginx
      volumes: 
        - .:/app
      links:
        - web:web
      ports: 
        - "80:80"
      depends_on:
        - web
volumes:
    pgdata:
```

**.env**.  (also located in root)

```
BASE_URL=localhost
SECRET_KEY=mySecretKey
ALLOWED_HOSTS=localhost,127.0.0.1,0.0.0.0
DEBUG=True

SQL_ENGINE=django.db.backends.postgresql
SQL_DATABASE=postgres
SQL_USER=postgres
SQL_PASSWORD=postgres
SQL_HOST=pgdb
SQL_PORT=5432

EMAIL_HOST_USER=my@mail.com
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD=myMailPassword

TEMPLATE_DIR=frontend/templates/frontend/
```

**Terminal Output** after running $docker-compose up in the root

```
pgdb is up-to-date
Recreating web ... done
Recreating djangodocker_nginx_1 ... done
Attaching to pgdb, web, djangodocker_nginx_1
nginx_1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
nginx_1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
nginx_1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
nginx_1  | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf is not a file or does not exist
web      | [2021-06-04 14:58:09 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
nginx_1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
web      | [2021-06-04 14:58:09 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (1)
web      | [2021-06-04 14:58:09 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
web      | [2021-06-04 14:58:09 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
nginx_1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
nginx_1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
nginx_1  | 2021/06/04 14:58:09 [notice] 1#1: using the "epoll" event method
nginx_1  | 2021/06/04 14:58:09 [notice] 1#1: nginx/1.20.1
nginx_1  | 2021/06/04 14:58:09 [notice] 1#1: built by gcc 10.2.1 20201203 (Alpine 10.2.1_pre1) 
nginx_1  | 2021/06/04 14:58:09 [notice] 1#1: OS: Linux 4.19.121-linuxkit
nginx_1  | 2021/06/04 14:58:09 [notice] 1#1: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1048576:1048576
nginx_1  | 2021/06/04 14:58:09 [notice] 1#1: start worker processes
nginx_1  | 2021/06/04 14:58:09 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 23
nginx_1  | 2021/06/04 14:58:09 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 24
nginx_1  | 2021/06/04 14:58:09 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 25
nginx_1  | 2021/06/04 14:58:09 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 26
pgdb     | 
pgdb     | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
pgdb     | 
pgdb     | 2021-06-04 14:34:00.119 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.3 (Debian 13.3-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
pgdb     | 2021-06-04 14:34:00.120 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
pgdb     | 2021-06-04 14:34:00.120 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
pgdb     | 2021-06-04 14:34:00.125 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
pgdb     | 2021-06-04 14:34:00.134 UTC [27] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-06-04 14:21:19 UTC
pgdb     | 2021-06-04 14:34:00.151 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
web      | /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/environ/environ.py:628: UserWarning: /app/djangoDocker/.env doesn't exist - if you're not configuring your environment separately, create one.
web      |   warnings.warn(
```

**requirements.txt**

```
Django==3.2
gunicorn==20.0.4
djoser==2.1.0
django-environ

psycopg2-binary~=2.8.0
django-cors-headers==3.5.0
django-templated-mail==1.1.1
djangorestframework==3.12.2
djangorestframework-simplejwt==4.7.0
```

Let me know in case any further information is required.

Comment: `docker-compose` and `.env` are in the same directory?

Comment: @Jeet Patel yes sir, both are in the root directory of the project

Comment: rename your file `.en.dev` may be this will work.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Jeet, unfortunately it did not help. If I only change the file name it is still looking for .env and hence throws an (different) error that .env is not being found. If I change the filename in env_file too, the exact same error as in my question occurs (still with .env in it, even after rebuilding everything)

Answer (score 1):

Until now I do not know what caused the error, but in case anyone else has the same problem: switching to [python-decouple](https://pypi.org/project/python-decouple/) instead of django-environ fixed it. Of course you have to adapt everything in settings.py accordingly, f.e. add `from decouple import config` and `DEBUG = config('DEBUG', default=False, cast=bool)`.

Comment: i have been looking at a ton of different questions and this worked! Had docker-compose env file setup but django-environ could not read from it for some reason. python-decouple worked great